# Question mark icons showing up for quotation marks when there's a UTF-8 character encoding

Tags: html, css, encoding, utf-8

For some reason, after I add:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" >
```

between my head tags, certain symbols (namely quotation marks) show up as diamond-shape icons with question marks in the middle, as if that symbol is not found. Anyone know what's up?

Comment: Are you using a serveur side script? and Are your quotation marks like `&laquo;` `&raquo;` ?

Comment: No for both questions. I'm just using normal quotations within my html.

Comment: Finally got it working, I'm not exactly sure how but converting to UTF-8 encoding was a step in the right direction. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your text editor is saving your file, including the quotation marks, in some encoding that isn't UTF-8 (most likely CP1252). Convert the file to actually be UTF-8 and try again.

Comment: Yep, ANSI was the default encoding that my text editor was set to use. I converted to UTF-8 but now there's other strange symbols showing up for my quotation marks and symbols... little square boxed with the numbers 0514 inside of them. Weird.

Comment: 0514 sounds like U+0514 (CYRILLIC CAPITAL LETTER LHA). Sounds like the conversion didn't quite go right.

Answer (score 1):

Are these regular quote characters (ASCII 34) or the dreaded "[smart quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_quotes#Smart_quotes)"? They're probably [smart quotes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_quotes#Smart_quotes). This typically happens when programmers cut/paste content from a word processor document. I recommend changing them to regular quotes. Doing so doesn't impact the content. It'll just give you cleaner markup and avoid annoying encoding issues.