# Ember.js Todo MVC with Brunch.io - symbols appear as question mark

Tags: css, sass

Hello I'm trying to do Ember.js TodoMVC tutorial with Brunch.io Coffeescript and sass-brunch@1.8.1(it uses libsass)

When I run it `check`, `destroy` symbols don't show up. `Check all` symbol shows as question mark.

[image]

And the `scss` file has this:

```
#todo-list li .toggle:after {
    content: '✔';
...
}

#toggle-all:before {
    content: '»';
...
}

#todo-list li .destroy:after {
    content: '✖';
}
```

**How do I fix this problem?**

Comment: You wrote the Sass or a 3rd party?  Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10393462/placing-unicode-character-in-css-content-value or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6256964/question-mark-icons-showing-up-for-quotation-marks-when-theres-a-utf-8-characte

Comment: it is just a css in a scss file. css was provided by the tutorial gonna refactor it to scss later.

Comment: oh it works when it is typed like \2716